# Can we start making a real production app using sneak peak GDK?

Tags: google-glass, google-gdk

At this moment we have a sneak peak GDK and there are rumors that final GDK will come by this summer along with a public google glass device.

Now, we plan to make our google glass app built on GDK and at this moment we can only use sneak peak GDK. So we basically plan to build app along with new GDK SDKs appearing so this summer we can immediately publish our GDK apps once Google starts accepting such apps.

How safe is that we start building using existing GDK? Can anyone confirm it will not be drastically changes so we don't end up in ever-changing loop?

I see that Glass guys are watching this tag so I hope someone of them can give us a direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Disclaimer: I am another Glass Explorer and *not* a Google employee ... however I have experience in several large corporations involved in software.]

I would expect to have to make minor and perhaps major adjustments in any Glassware application development that we do.  In fact, as we find anomalies or other inconsistencies, I would hope that our feedback and requests would actually help shape the initially non-beta released GDK. If we get into a "continually updating" cycle as the GDK evolves, so be it.

Just my opinion and expectation. We will focus on modularizing and hiding important elements so changes to match a new GDK can be contained.